# How to get all NFTs by creator?

Tags: solana

I am working on a script to identify the number of holders and the number of NFTs each holder has. Well, let's start by getting all NFTs one creator has. How can I do that?

I tried the function [get_token_accounts_by_owner](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/api.html) but this shows only the last 90 tokens and not all of them.